# Вывод цены на странице из csv

Tags: php, массивы

Есть прайс в csv формате. Нужно найти и вывести цену на страницу, связующее звено - SKU товара.

Сначала прайс переводим в многомерный массив.

```
$data = parse_csv_file('price.csv');

$result = array_filter($data, function ($k) {
    return $k['0'] === '25005'; // вмето sku должна приходить переменная
});

echo 'Price: '.$result['2'];
```

Далее находим массив ножного товара.

```
Array
(
    [19] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25005 //SKU
            [1] => Description
            [2] => 255 //Price
        )

)
```

А теперь нужно вывести цену с этого массива на странице.

Comment: проще всего сделать так, чтобы функция parse_csv_file() индексировала возвращаемый массив через $sku. тогда просто echo $data[$sku][2];

Comment: А если не трогать трогать парсер?

Answer (score 0):

Может кому-то понадобится. Решил так:

```
function Price($sku)
{
    global $ROOT_DIR;
    $data = parse_csv_file($ROOT_DIR . '/downloads/price.csv');
    $price_text = "no price";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
        if ($data[$i][0] == $sku) {
            if ($data[$i][2] > '') {
                $price_text = ($data[$i][2]) . ' грн';
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return $price_text;
}
```